# KickStart Centos Says Please insert Centos Disc 1 to Continue

Tags: linux

I am trying to create a basic kickstart installation using Centos 6.4 DVD. I followed the following guide:

http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/35-linux/128-building-a-custom-centos-6-kickstart-disc-part-1

Here is What I did in a zip (in case the link provided is too long to read):

1> Copied all the required packages from the DVD to isolinux/Packages

2> Resolved all dependencies

3> create repo using

```
cd ~/kickstart_build/isolinux
declare -x discinfo=`head -1 .discinfo`
createrepo -u "media://$discinfo" -g ~/kickstart_build/comps.xml ~/kickstart_build/isolinux
```

4> Created the iso using

```
mkisofs -o custom.iso -b isolinux.bin -c boot.cat -no-emul-boot \
   -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -R -J -v -T isolinux/
```

Now , When I tried to install it in a Virtual Machine, this was the result

**Installation Result**

**1> Found Local Media**

**2> Created All partitions**

**3> Resolved all Dependencies**

**4> Actual Installation starts and it halts saying "Please insert Centos Disc 1 to Continue"**

This is a snapshot of my ks.cfg

**ks.cfg**

```
#platform=x86, AMD64, or Intel EM64T
#version=DEVEL
# Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled
# Install OS instead of upgrade
install
# Use CDROM installation media
cdrom
# Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $1$AxSWVPvq$HC4VrvE2waXgPiywrvPlZ1
# System authorization information
auth  --useshadow  --passalgo=sha512
# Use graphical install
graphical
firstboot --disable
# System keyboard
keyboard us
# System language
lang en_US
# SELinux configuration
selinux --disabled
# Installation logging level
logging --level=info
# Reboot after installation
reboot
# System timezone
timezone --isUtc Asia/Kolkata
# Network information
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0 --onboot=on
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr --md5pass="$1$TTaOYB53$sud09Jtqq4KyIPywRd4zw/"
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel
# Disk partitioning information
part /boot --fstype="ext3" --size=100
part pv.01 --size=20960 --grow
volgroup VolGroup00 pv.01
logvol /        --fstype ext3 --vgname=VolGroup00 --size=10240  --name=LogVol00
logvol /swap    --fstype swap --vgname=VolGroup00 --size=2048  --name=LogVol01
logvol /var     --fstype ext3 --vgname=VolGroup00 --size=4960   --grow --name=LogVol02
logvol /home    --fstype ext3 --vgname=VolGroup00 --size=512    --name=LogVol04
logvol /tmp     --fstype ext3 --vgname=VolGroup00 --size=512    --name=LogVol05
logvol /opt     --fstype ext3 --vgname=VolGroup00 --size=5360   --name=LogVol03


%packages
@base
@general-desktop

%end
```

Kindly help me solve this. Been scratching on it for a long. And please pardon me if the question is off-topic or too subjective.